# How does Dragon Ball Super's anime release before the manga?

Tags: anime-production, dragon-ball-super

The anime is currently being released way faster than the manga according to my sources. In most cases of anime production (correct me if I'm wrong). But there is a mangaka (in this case toriyama-sensei) who creates content for the story called canon and releases that content via manga. Once a manga gets licensed and published by a major studio like Funimation or Bandai it becomes an anime, gets toys, games, t-shirts etc. But how is it that Dragon Ball Super is actually ahead of it's own manga?

Comment: Probably fillers :)

Comment: See I've considered that but so far the story has been the same save for how to goku vs hit battle ended. Now I don't know if kaioken + SSB is possible or if SSR -> SSB -> SSR is possible, or maybe both are. I dunno. Does this sort of thing happen often? It's the first series I've seen that releases before the manga that it comes from does.

Comment: could be the Mangaka has had input into the series. i think i remember reading somewhere that it was the case with all the Dragonball Movies

Comment: Was that also the case with the GT series?

Comment: @ardaozkal much of it is Fillers, but a lot is Canon. We saw the opponents in the tournament in the anime before they were fully revealed in the manga, and many of the fights went mostly the same way. Im sure Toriyama is working diligently with the Anime team to tell them about the canon events he plans on drawing in the manga, and the anime team mostly follows them (though goku has shown several times more strength in the anime than he should actually have in filler)

Comment: @Ryan this is another thing that drives me up a wall. Like was SSB kaiokenx10 just a mistranslation or something?

Comment: @KazRodgers well in the anime filler, its not. Hit clearly conveys that Gokus Kaioken was at least at 3-4 (or something between 2 and 5), but then corrects himself to say its greater before goku says 10. Of course in the manga, we know Goku doesn't use KaioKen at all to defeat Hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that this time around, the anime series is the original work, while the manga is the adaptation.

This is of course in contrast with the original Dragon Ball series, which were written and illustrated by Akira Toriyama and published in Weekly Shōnen Jump, and only latter adapted into anime.

The precedence of the anime in the case of Dragon Ball Super has been widely reported, even though the first issue of the manga was published first (June 20, July 5 the first episode of the anime). Here are some sample sources (limited to 2 links for new user, I'll edit later)

- [Dragon Ball Super TV Anime Gets Manga Adaptation](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-05-18/dragon-ball-super-tv-anime-gets-manga-adaptation/.88276) 2015-05-18
- [Dragon Ball Super getting companion manga](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/05/19/dragon-ball-super-getting-companion-manga) 2015-05-19
- [DB Super getting ahead of manga?](https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/484ea1/db_super_getting_ahead_of_manga/) 2016-04

Also, the manga series is credited to Toyotarō, both story and art (see for example [here](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=18511)), with Akira Toriyama credited variously with original concept/story, or as original creator. Wikipedia goes as far as to say "Written by Akira Toriyama / Illustrated by Toyotarō", but that seems to be an overstatement. The cover art of chapters 1 reads: "Manga by Toyotarō. Created by Toriyama Akira".

This means that it is unlikely that the manga has any particular input from Toriyama, other that the one that goes to the storyboard and the animation team.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to accept the answer. I swore I did it some time ago. :-(