# How does a series go from manga to anime?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history, manga-production, manga-history

In a previous [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34308/how-does-dragon-ball-supers-anime-release-before-the-manga), I asked about Dragon Ball Super being released before its manga. My question here is about the life cycle of a manga becoming an anime.

From my understanding, an artist or mangaka creates their comic called manga and it gets published by a major studio if it's deemed worthy. From there if it cultivates a big enough fan-base it becomes licensed by a studio like Viz, Funimation or Bandai. And from there it becomes a game, movie, t-shirt, toy, etc.

Is that the way most anime's come into play? If not, what is the proper life cycle from drawing to manga to anime?

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/11446/7579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anime might be produced based from many types of different stuff, not limited to manga, but also other stuff, like light novels. There are also some anime that aren't based on any manga.

> From my understanding an artist or mangaka creates their comic called manga and it gets published by a major studio if it's deemed worthy.

Yes, this is pretty much correct. The mangaka can release their own manga too, but it is less likely to be as popular.

The mangakas usually work together with magazines like Jump where they have someone they can show their ideas, drawn simply. If their idea gets accepted, they start on producing it with more details.

> From there if it cultivates a big enough fan-base it becomes licensed by a studio like viz, funimation or bandai. And from there it becomes a game, movie, t-shirt, toy etc.

Yes, this is also correct. The mangakas license their manga with some companies to make it an anime, and swags of it.

I really recommend you to read the [manga](http://myanimelist.net/manga/9711/Bakuman) or watch the [anime](http://myanimelist.net/anime/7674/Bakuman) of "Bakuman." which tells the story of 2 teens producing manga (and aiming to get one produced into an anime), with very good amount of details on every part of the production cycle.

Comment: Ok so magazines are a publisher of manga but they are also different from studios. Kind of like a newspaper and news broadcast. I guess would be a good way to compare em?

Comment: Also a follow-up to that. When a publisher decides to buy a mangaka's work. Do they get a team and become a leader of that team? Or do they continue to work solo?

Comment: @KazRogers first comment: kind of. More like book publisher IDONTKNOWANYFOREIGNONES and Sony Pictures. Second comment: depends on mangaka

Comment: Yoshikawa Miki of Yamada-kun to 7-nin Majo was assistant of Mashima Hiro of Fairy Tail. Most big mangakas work in a team. It'd be near impossible for them to meet deadlines on their own since they need to think of the story idea while also drawing and toning